# LINQ query .ToDictionary with Tuple int key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm wondering if is it possible to do a linq query like this:

```
Dictionary<(int,int), object)> entity = _context.Table.ToDictionary((i => i.IDOrigin, i.IDDestiny), o => o);
```

I know that it's possible with an unique key `.ToDictionay(i => i.Key, o => o.Value);` but in this case this table has a double PK and I need both as keys.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try it? What happened? Did you get an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to tweak your call a bit:

```cs
_context.Table.ToDictionary(i => (i.IDOrigin, i.IDDestiny), o => o)
```

All I've moved is the brackets: you still want `i` as a regular lambda expression parameter, but you want the *result* of the lambda to be a tuple literal, which is the `(i.IDOrigin, i.IDDestiny)` part.

Note that the `o => o` part is unnecessary - if you don't specify a lambda expression for projecting from a source element to a value, `ToDictionary` uses the source element *as* the value. So you can use:

```cs
_context.Table.ToDictionary(i => (i.IDOrigin, i.IDDestiny))
```

Comment: Well, that's seems pretty logical now , I feel a bit silly now hahaha Thank you so much! Works perfectly